# Scala Gatling http call return a string or access session outside of scenario

Tags: java, scala, performance-testing, gatling

I have a method which is called

```
 def getOAuth2Token() : HttpRequestBuilder = {
   http("Get OAuth2 Token from Token Converter")
     .post(tokenConverterTokenEndpoint)
     .header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationFormUrlEncoded)
     .formParam("client_id", "client")
     .formParam("client_secret", "secret")
     .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
     .formParam("scope", "api:service")
     .check(status.is(HttpResponseStatus.OK.code()))
     .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("oAuth2Token"))
 }
```

That saves "oAuth2Token". How can I use this when not in a Scenario e.g

```
val request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(enrollmentUri)
      .header(HttpHeaderNames.Authorization, session => {
        "Bearer " + session("oAuth2Token").as[String]
      })
      .post(body)
      .build()
```

This currently gives me an error of Missing parameter sessions.

I would like to either:

1. Use the session here so I can use the token
2. Create a new method similar to the first code block that returns the token

Comment: why are you trying to use it 'when not in a Scenario'? What are you attempting to achieve in your second code block?

Comment: @JamesWarr The idea is to create some setup data, and I don't want this to count towards my run times

Comment: you're generally much better of having any setup run outside of the scenario, and you won't be able to pass session data to such a call anyway. You can either do it yourself in the setUp block, or if you want to use the gatling DSL - via another simulation that runs first and saves the relevant data to a csv file.